# Apollo-client's cacheRedirect vs dataIdFromObject

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to prevent re-fetch of previously cached data. But the documentation provides a couple of ways of achieving this through [cacheRedirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#data-normalization) and [dataIdFromObject](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#cache-redirects-with-cacheredirects). I'm trying to understand when one technique is used over the other.

He's an example flow using `dataIdFromObject` -- would this provide enough context for Apollo to fetch the detail view data from cache, or do I additionally need a cacheRedirect to link the `uuid` query?

List view query:

```
query ListView {
   books {
     uuid
     title
     abstract
   }
}
```

Detail view query:

```
query DetailView {
   book(uuid: $uuid) {
     uuid
     title
     abstract
   }
}
```

cache constructor args with `dataIdFromObject`:

```
new InMemoryCache({
   dataIdFromObject: object => {
     switch (object.__typename) {
       case 'book': return `book:${object.uuid}`;
       default: return defaultDataIdFromObject(object); // default handling
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are incorrect when you say

> But the documentation provides a couple of ways of achieving this
>   through cacheRedirects and dataIdFromObject.

I believe only `cacheRedirects` achieve what you want.

`dataIdFromObject` allows you to customize how ApolloClient should uniquely identify your objects. By default, ApolloClient assumes your objects have either a `id` or `_id` property, and it combines the object `__typename` with the `id` property to create a unique identifier.

By providing a `dataIdFromObject` function, you can customize this unique identifier. For example, if all of you objects have an id which is a `uuid`, then you could supply a `dataIdFromObject` function which simply instructs ApolloClient to use the object's `id` property, without appending `__typename`.